# How to acces google test fixture static variable

Tags: c++, testing, static, googletest, fixtures

I would like to test one of my classes with google test. The initialization of this class takes a lot of time and resources, so I would like to do it only once for all of my tests cases, so I am trying to use fixture with SetUpTestSuite(). In my fixture I declare a variable:

```
static MyClassToBeTested my_class;
```

In my test cases, I would like to access the `my_class` variable.

During compiling I get the following error:

```
undefined reference to 'MyTest::my_class'
```

I tried to access it with simply `my_class` and also `MyTest::my_class`:

```
class MyTest : public ::testing::Test {
protected:
    static MyClassToBeTested my_class;
    static void SetUpTestSuite() {
        //doing some stuff here
    }
};
TEST_F(MyTest, first_test) {
    ASSERT_EQ(my_class.foo(), 5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define your static variable

```
class MyTest : public ::testing::Test {
protected:
    static MyClassToBeTested my_class;
    static void SetUpTestSuite() {
        //doing some stuff here
    }
};

MyClassToBeTested MyTest::my_class;
```

Comment: Try to limit your code to the minimal number of line and post it and also your compilation command line.